# Why is R (in my example) very slow for handling dates/datetimes?

Tags: r, performance, date, datetime

I have a list of 40 dataframes with about 250k rows and I want to append a new variable to each dataframes. This new variable `period` is calculated from another variable which contains Date objects, the transformation is very simple, if the year part of the date is lower than 2015 period is set to "new" else "old".

I thought the computation would be very fast using vectorization but it takes about 41 seconds to complete ! (Use a for loop or a lapply gave the same performances).

Reproducible example :

```
datas.d <- function(nDf, nRow) {
  lapply(seq_len(nDf), function(x) {
    data.frame(
      id1 = sample(7e8:9e8, nRow), 
      id2 = sample(1e9, nRow), 
      id3 = sample(1e9, nRow), 
      date = sample(seq(as.Date("2012-01-01"), Sys.Date(), by = 1), nRow, rep = TRUE), 
      code1 = sample(10, nRow, rep = TRUE), 
      code2 = sample(10, nRow, rep = TRUE), 
      code3 = sample(10, nRow, rep = TRUE)
    )
  })
}

datasDate <- datas.d(40, 25e4)

forLoopDate <- function(datas) {
  for (i in seq_along(datas)) {
    datas[[i]]$period <- rep("old", nrow(datas[[i]]))
    datas[[i]]$period[format(datas[[i]]$date, "%Y") == "2015"] <- "new"
  }
  return(datas)
}

> system.time(forLoopDate(datasDate))
utilisateur     système      écoulé 
      41.46        0.31       41.84
```

I already experienced slow performances when I coerced strings into Dates in a 800k rows dataframe so I suspected the date manipulation of being guilty for the bad performances. The R Profiler confirmed it :

```
Rprof(tmp <- tempfile())
datas <- forLoopDate(datasDate)
Rprof(NULL)
summaryRprof(tmp)
$by.self
                  self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
"format.POSIXlt"      39.34    94.16      39.34     94.16
"as.POSIXlt.Date"      1.80     4.31       1.80      4.31
"=="                   0.36     0.86       0.36      0.86
"forLoopDate"          0.22     0.53      41.78    100.00
"format.Date"          0.06     0.14      41.20     98.61
```

So I tried the same transformation skiping the Date formatting, i.e. directly use a string for the year. The performance gain is unequivocal :

I also test it with another formatting function, `year` from the lubridate package. The formatting is very fast, I guess because it's doing at the C level ?

```
datas.s <- function(nDf, nRow) {
  lapply(seq_len(nDf), function(x) {
    data.frame(
      id1 = sample(7e8:9e8, nRow), 
      id2 = sample(1e9, nRow), 
      id3 = sample(1e9, nRow), 
      date = sample(2012:2015, nRow, rep = TRUE), 
      code1 = sample(10, nRow, rep = TRUE), 
      code2 = sample(10, nRow, rep = TRUE), 
      code3 = sample(10, nRow, rep = TRUE)
    )
  })
}

datasString <- datas.s(40, 25e4)

forLoopString <- function(datas) {
  for (i in seq_along(datas)) {
    datas[[i]]$period <- rep("old", nrow(datas[[i]]))
    datas[[i]]$period[datas[[i]]$date == "2015"] <- "new"
  }
  return(datas)
}

library(lubridate)
forLoopDate2 <- function(datas) {
  for (i in seq_along(datas)) {
    datas[[i]]$period <- rep("old", nrow(datas[[i]]))
    datas[[i]]$period[year(datas[[i]]$date) == 2015] <- "new"
  }
  return(datas)
}

library(microbenchmark)
mbm <- microbenchmark(
  date = datas <- forLoopDate(datasDate), 
  string = datas <- forLoopString(datasString),
  lubridate = datas <- forLoopDate2(datasDate),
  times = 10L)

> mbm
Unit: seconds
expr       min        lq      mean    median       uq       max neval
date 41.502728 41.561497 41.649533 41.652306 41.69218 41.875110    10
string  4.119266  4.131186  4.167809  4.166946  4.17993  4.239481    10
lubridate  2.088281  2.105413  2.133042  2.111710  2.15794  2.250739    10
```

And here comes a lot of questions !

_Why formatting/converting Dates is that slow with R ?

_Can I improve the performance of my code using Base R ? What are the good practices, for performance purpose, when handling Dates/datetimes ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `format` function that can return many different formats, can be expected to be quite slow. If you are happy with lubridate's `year` function, you could just use its (very simple) code:

```
as.POSIXlt(x, tz = tz(x))$year + 1900
```

In general, you should avoid conversions between any types/classes and characters when performance matters. That will often be slow. It's better to do numeric calculations (e.g., you could use the integers that are the basis of Date variables, but that leads to problems with leap years, so it is better to use POSIXlt, which takes care of this for you).